# Not passing values through url nodejs

Tags: html, node.js, express, authentication, ejs

I have created a login system, and am trying to hash the passwords, or not send them through the url. I have a form on the front end, which basically receives the users input, compares it to the password stored in the DB, and if it is the same, then simply allow them into the site, if it is not, then don't. However, it is easily accessible through the url. if the password is correct, you can see it in the url. I was wondering if there is a way for this not to happen? Not sure if there is. Thanks in advance

code below:

the site isn't hosted yet, so cannot share that, but here is the code...

front end:

```
 <form method="GET" action="/login">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-user" id="inputUsername" name="inputUsername" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter Email Address...">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control form-control-user" id="exampleInputPassword" name="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox small">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="customCheck">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="customCheck">Remember Me</label>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <button class="button" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
                <hr>
                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                  <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Login with Google
                </a>
                <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Login with Facebook
                </a>
              </form>
```

backend:

```
app.get('/login', (req, res) => {

//declaring variables
const inputUsername = req.query.inputUsername;
const inputPassword = req.query.inputPassword;





var userLogin = "select * from login where USERNAME = '" + inputUsername + "' AND PASSWORD = '" + inputPassword + "'";
ibmdb.open(dbString, function (err, conn) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
    conn.query(userLogin, function (err, rows) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            }
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                console.log('trying to render index')
                //userAuth = "true";
                userName = inputUsername;

                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    firstName = rows[i]['FN']
                    lastName = rows[i]['LN']
                    company = rows[i]['COMPANY']
                    
                }
                res.redirect('/index')
            } else {
               // userAuth = "false";
                res.render('login.ejs')   
                alert('Incorrect username or password. Please try again')
            }

           
        })
    })
})
```

and the info gets passed through the url like this: localhost:9999/login?inputUsername=testUser1&inputPassword=testPass1

Answer (score 0):

Change to a POST request

Just change `method="GET"` to `method="POST"`, then in the backend change `app.get('/login',` to `app.post('/login',` and `req.query.inputUsername` to `req.body.inputUsername` (inc the other one).

---

You should also use prepared queries, as-is your script is open to sql injection. So change `where USERNAME = '" + inputUsername + "'`  to `where USERNAME = ?`  (inc the other one) and pass the params like `conn.query(userLogin, [inputUsername, inputPassword], function`

Comment: np, there is quite abit which needs tweaking ;p something to note is if you intend to use SSO (login with Google/Facebook) you will need to implement login differently, most likely with http://www.passportjs.org/ which would wipe out most of your current code

Comment: followed what you did, it worked nicely. however, when i get to the second part, thats where it seems to fail. It is probably due to incorrect formatting. I have it like this.  var userLogin = "select * from login where USERNAME = ? AND PASSWORD = ?"   It gives me the error, "cb && cb(err, db);
          ^

TypeError: cb is not a function"

Comment: to reply to the recent comment. I am not intending on using fb or google login. I am using creating an application that will allow a specific set of predefined users to login only. Thanks for mentioning that thought :)

Comment: yeah I mentioned it because of the HTML code which says login with.., what db lib are you using, not sure what would cause `"cb && cb(err, db); ^ TypeError: cb`

Comment: yes definitely. could you point me in the direction to finding the lib please... sorry, not sure where I could find it

Comment: I mean what is `ibmdb`? I can look up the docs and find if its `= ?` for the prepared query, it might be something else, which is causing the error

Comment: i am using ibm db2, with version ^2.7.1. is that what you mean?

Comment: ok, your need to follow: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db/v/2.2.0#prepareApi - though it looks like it should work in query() https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db/v/2.2.0#3-querysqlquery--bindingparameters-callback

Comment: got it working. it was simple misunderstanding of syntax on my part. thanks for help!